# nested_attrubutes not assosiate with parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

### I can not associate children record with parent using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

My code:

```
# app/model/report.rb
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, class_name: Asset::Photo, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end

# app/model/asset/photo.rb
class Asset::Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'asset_photos'

  belongs_to :report

  validates :file, :report, presence: true

  mount_uploader :file, Asset::Photo::FileUploader
end
```

#### then i execute in console and get:

```
> a = Report.new rating: 5, user: User.last, 
      photos_attributes: [{file: File.open(Rails.root+'spec/fixtures/test.png')}]
> a.save # false
> a.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0xba758360 
   @base=#<Report id: nil, rating: 5, user_id: 18, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, 
   @messages={:"photos.report"=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

#### how to fix `"photos.report"=>["can't be blank"]`? Thanks :)

Comment: Change your Photo validations with report_id instead of just report

Comment: the same sh1t :( `@messages={:"photos.report_id"=>["can't be blank"]}`

Comment: the doc specifies you should be using inverse_of when validating the parent model exists and when active record has trouble identifying the inverse association, maybe you could try with that. Maybe the class_name is what's causing all this... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model

Comment: I've added `belongs_to :report, inverse_of: :photos` and `has_many :photos, class_name: Asset::Photo, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :report` still the same issue :(

Comment: @mlainez wow men you are right `has_many :photos, class_name: Asset::Photo, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :report` fixed the issue, please submit your answer! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that when you save the `report`, it tries to save the `photos` first. The problem is that there is no saved `report` object yet because it is still only in memory. The solution is to use `inverse_of`.

The `inverse_of` option tells `ActiveRecord` to be more clever and look in memory before trying to fetch the object through the association. By doing so, it finds the unsaved report in memory and recognized it as the one you are validating against.

Usually, as the [Rails doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model) specifies, it will try to guess the inverse association based on heuristics from the name of the association. But the fact you're using a `class_name` makes it impossible for Rails to guess forcing you to specify you own `inverse_of`.

Try replacing your belongs_to with:

```
belongs_to :report, inverse_of: :photos
```

And your has_many with:

```
has_many :photos, class_name: Asset::Photo, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :report
```